# Submit multiple value when using Ajax.Request and Starbox

Tags: ajax, request

I'm using [starbox](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/starbox/) and I have a function defined like:

```
document.observe('starbox:rated', saveStar);
function saveStar(event) {
  new Ajax.Request('saverating.htm', {
      parameters: event.memo
  });
}
```

I can retrieve the event parameters (rated, average, etc) in my controller.  However, I also want to send another variable in the Ajax request.  I've tried

```
new Ajax.Request('saverating.htm', {
  parameters: {ratingValue: event.memo, othervar: 12}
});
```

and

```
new Ajax.Request('saverating.htm', {
  var params = {ratingvalue: event.memo, othervar: 12};
  parameters: params
});
```

but that only sends the `othervar`, not the `event.memo`.  How can I send the event.memo value as well as another variable?  Do I have to concatenate the rating and the othervar before the request?  Is this because event.memo is an object?

Answer (score 0):

`event` is a reserved word and might have special meaning depending on the context. Try naming your variable differently:

```
new Ajax.Request('saverating.htm', {
    parameters: { ratingValue: evt.memo, othervar: 12 }
});
```